# mit der ihr German

Tags: grammar, meaning

Can someone translate me this sentence in English and explain to me how "mit der ihr" works?

Sie fuhr mit der ihr eigentümlichen, drolligen Aufmerksamkeit.

Comment: `mit der ihr eigenen [Aufmerksamkeit]`can be re-prased as `mit der Aufmerksamkeit, welche ihr (zu-)eigen ist`: so, `die ihr zueigen ist` gets `die ihr eigene`

Answer (score 5):

Main sentence:

> **Sie fuhr.**
>   **She drove.**

With what (how) did she drive?

> Sie fuhr **mit Aufmerksamkeit**.
>   Sie drove **with attention**.

Really just any attention or a special attention?

> Sie fuhr mit **der** Aufmerksamkeit.
>   Sie drove with **the** attention.

(definite article transforms *any*-thing into some specific thing. Compare: Indefinite: **An** apple is red. Definite: **The** apple is red.)

Can you describe this special attention?

> Sie fuhr mit der **drolligen** Aufmerksamkeit.
>   Sie drove with the **droll** attention.

Thats it? Maybe you can describe it even more?

> Sie fuhr mit der ***ihr* eigentümlichen,** drolligen Aufmerksamkeit.
>   Sie drove with the **to *her* belonging,** droll attention.

(I know, the last sentence is not perfect english, but it perfectly reflects the German sentence, and you hopefully will understand it.) (Here you have a list of descriptions, and the two items of this list must be separated by a comma in German)

### ... mit der ihr ...

"Mit" is a preposition ("with") that tells us, that the words that come after it, describe something, that is attached to something that what was written before this word. (»Mann *mit* Hut« = "Man *with* hat").

"Der" is the definite article of "Aufmerksamkeit" (female, singular, dative case). Nominativ: Die Aufmerksamkeit. Genitiv: Der Aufmerksamkeit. Dativ: Der Aufmerksamkeit. Akkusativ: Die Aufmerksamkeit.

"Ihr" is a demonstrative pronoun that tells us to who this attention belongs. (»Ihr« = "her")

Answer (score 1):

"mit der ihr" can be rephrased as Burki already said. You could roughly translate it into "with her own" although it makes little sense without a context. It´s used to describe a behaviour very special to one person.

Your sentence could be translated into:

`She drove with the droll attention that she was known for.`

Comment: Maybe even "with her very own" or "with her peculiar".

Comment: Yes, absolutely.